# Call JButton pressed animation using mnemonic

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, mnemonics

Heres a sample code, i´ve tried most of the JButton settings but couldn´t figure it out.

```
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class FailedMnemonic extends JFrame implements Runnable{

    /*
     * 
     * F4 to call button action
     * ESC to dispose Dialog
     * 
     * */

    public FailedMnemonic() {
        setSize(200, 100);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setLayout(null);
        Panel p = new Panel(this);
        p.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 60);
        add(p);
    };

    public static void main(String args[]){
        FailedMnemonic f = new FailedMnemonic();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

    }

    public class Panel extends JPanel{

        final JFrame f;
        Action a = new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                /*Here should be called the pressed animation from the button, dont know how
                 * maybe i should add the button as parameter on the dialog class so when is dispose the button returns to its original state*/
                Dialog d = new Dialog(f, "...", true);
                d.setSize(500, 200);
                d.setVisible(true);
            }
        };

        JButton b = new JButton();

        public Panel(JFrame f){
            this.f = f;
            setLayout(null);
            b.setBounds(0, 0, 150, 50);
            b.setAction(a);
            a.putValue(Action.MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_F4);
            getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(
                    KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F4, 0), "meh");
            getActionMap().put("meh", a);
            b.setText("CLICK ME");
            add(b);
        }

        public class Dialog extends JDialog{

            public Dialog(JFrame OWNER, String title, boolean modal){
                super(OWNER, title, modal);
                setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                addEscapeListener(this);
            }

            public void addEscapeListener(final JDialog dialog) {
                ActionListener escListener = new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        dialog.setVisible(false);
                    }};
                dialog.getRootPane().registerKeyboardAction(escListener,
                        KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0),
                        JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Imports didn´t get into the block code

Comment: `Imports didn´t get into the block code` - all the code needs to be indented 4 spaces. Easiest way to do this is to select the code and then click on the `{}` button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call your classes "Frame" and "Dialog". There are AWT components with that name so it gets confusing. Use more description names (even if it is quick demo code).

> Call JButton pressed animation using mnemonic

On Windows I get the animation when using Alt+F4, which is the mnemonic. I don't get the animation when I use F4, which is the Key Binding.

This makes sense because using `Key Bindings` you just map a `KeyStroke` to an `Action`. It doesn't know the Action belongs to a button.

If you want to see the button animation then I would suggest you need to:

1. Add an normal ActionListener to the button to display your dialog
2. Create an Action for the Key Bindings. This Action would then invoke `button.doClick()`.

Note, you may also want to check out [Escape Key and Dialog](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/10/17/escape-key-and-dialog/) for a more complete Action. This Action will support closing of combo box drop downs using the escape key.

Comment: I´ve tried your suggestions. It actually works, the animation triggers, the problem now happens when the dialog is disposed the action triggers again and the dialog shows up again.

Comment: `when the dialog is disposed the action triggers again and the dialog shows up again.` - that is why I said you need a separate ActionLIstener and Action. You did not implement the suggestion correctly and did not repost your code so I can't help further.